# How can I make my subview with a binding to mainview disappear and cleanly reappear?

Tags: swiftui

#### What I expect to happen

I have a meditation view that has an animation subview with a binding property `inhaling` that should appear when a button is pressed.

When the animation subview appears, it should start the animation from the beginning. It's the Apple meditation breathing animation basically: it starts as a small ball and gets bigger as inhaling is true, and then smaller as inhaling is false.

[image: 1]

When the user presses the button again, the animation should disappear.

When the user then again presses the button, a second time, it should start the animation subview with a binding clean. Meaning the subview is a small ball and gets big again. Like the first time.

```swift
struct Meditation: View {
    @State var startBreathingAnimation = false
    @State var inhaling = false
    @State var infoText = "Start a mediation"

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ZStack {
                if startBreathingAnimation {
                    BreathAnimation(inhaling: $inhaling)
                        .onChange(of: inhaling) { newValue in
                            if newValue {
                                infoText = "Breath in..."
                            } else {
                                infoText = "Breath out..."
                            }                                }
                        .onDisappear {
                            infoText = "Start your meditation" // Never executed?
                        }
                } else {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            Text(infoText)
            Button("Toggle") {
                startBreathingAnimation.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

#### What actually happens

The animation subview with a binding is not reset, newly initialized, but starts just where it left off after being "dismissed" with the button press.

When I don't add a binding property into the subview, it actually works as expected: it resets every time and gives me a "fresh" subview. But I do actually need to observe changes to the animation subview property `inhaling` in order to update the `infoText` property in the main view.

#### Reproducible example code, ready to copy into Xcode

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```swift
// Can be copied to Xcode directly
struct Meditation: View {
    @State var startBreathingAnimation = false
    @State var inhaling = false
    @State var infoText = "Start a mediation"

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ZStack {
                if startBreathingAnimation {
                    BreathAnimation(inhaling: $inhaling)
                        .onChange(of: inhaling) { newValue in
                            if newValue {
                                infoText = "Breath in..."
                            } else {
                                infoText = "Breath out..."
                            }                                }
                        .onDisappear {
                            infoText = "Start your meditation" // Never executed?
                        }
                } else {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            Text(infoText)
            Button("Toggle") {
                startBreathingAnimation.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


private let gradientStart = Color.accentColor.opacity(0.9)
private let gradientEnd = Color.accentColor.opacity(1.0)


private let gradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [gradientStart, gradientEnd]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
private let maskGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)

private let maxSize: CGFloat = 150
private let minSize: CGFloat = 30
private let inhaleTime: Double = 8
private let exhaleTime: Double = 8
private let pauseTime: Double = 1.5

private let numberOfPetals = 4
private let bigAngle = 360 / numberOfPetals
private let smallAngle = bigAngle / 2

private let ghostMaxSize: CGFloat = maxSize * 0.99
private let ghostMinSize: CGFloat = maxSize * 0.95

private struct Petals: View {
    let size: CGFloat
    let inhaling: Bool

    var isMask = false

    var body: some View {
        let petalsGradient = isMask ? maskGradient : gradient

        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<numberOfPetals) { index in
                petalsGradient
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .mask(
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: size, height: size)
                            .offset(x: inhaling ? size * 0.5 : 0)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(bigAngle * index)))
                    )
                    .blendMode(isMask ? .normal : .screen)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BreathAnimation: View {
    @State private var size = minSize
    @Binding var inhaling: Bool

    @State private var ghostSize = ghostMaxSize
    @State private var ghostBlur: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var ghostOpacity: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
//            Color.black
//                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            ZStack {
                // ghosting for exhaling
                Petals(size: ghostSize, inhaling: inhaling)
                    .blur(radius: ghostBlur)
                    .opacity(ghostOpacity)

                // the mask is important, otherwise there is a color
                // 'jump' when exhaling
                Petals(size: size, inhaling: inhaling, isMask: true)

                // overlapping petals
                Petals(size: size, inhaling: inhaling)
                Petals(size: size, inhaling: inhaling)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(smallAngle)))
                    .opacity(inhaling ? 0.8 : 0.6)
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(inhaling ? bigAngle : -smallAngle)))
            .drawingGroup()
        }
        .onAppear {
            performAnimations()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            size = minSize
            inhaling = false
            ghostSize = ghostMaxSize
            ghostBlur = 0
            ghostOpacity = 0
        }
    }
    func performAnimations() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: inhaleTime)) {
            inhaling = true
            size = maxSize
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: inhaleTime + pauseTime, repeats: false) { _ in
            ghostSize = ghostMaxSize
            ghostBlur = 0
            ghostOpacity = 0.8

            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: exhaleTime * 0.2, repeats: false) { _ in
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: exhaleTime * 0.6)) {
                    ghostBlur = 30
                    ghostOpacity = 0
                }
            }

            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: exhaleTime)) {
                inhaling = false
                size = minSize
                ghostSize = ghostMinSize
            }
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: inhaleTime + pauseTime + exhaleTime + pauseTime, repeats: false) { _ in

            // endless animation!
            performAnimations()
        }
    }

    private func performAnimations2() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: inhaleTime)) {
            inhaling = true
            size = maxSize
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: inhaleTime + pauseTime, repeats: false) { _ in
            ghostSize = ghostMaxSize
            ghostBlur = 0
            ghostOpacity = 0.8

            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: exhaleTime * 0.2, repeats: false) { _ in
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: exhaleTime * 0.6)) {
                    ghostBlur = 30
                    ghostOpacity = 0
                }
            }

            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: exhaleTime)) {
                inhaling = false
                size = minSize
                ghostSize = ghostMinSize
            }
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: inhaleTime + pauseTime + exhaleTime + pauseTime, repeats: false) { _ in

            // endless animation!
            performAnimations()
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        Meditation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue is not observed with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5, ie. if toggle on after off animation re-starts from initial state. What is you env? Or what I missed?

Comment: Or maybe it depends on where did you place Meditation view. I placed it directly into ContentView body (with nothing around).

Comment: Btw, previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144662/why-does-my-sub-view-animation-not-reset-its-view-properties-giving-me-a-fre had really reproducible issue, but I don't see it in current variant. (You'd better remove previous one to do not have same problem posts, it might confuse someone who will make search in the future.)

Comment: My env is Xcode 14 beta 3, and iOS 16 beta 3. And I place it directly to ContentView, too. With nothing around it. So maybe it is beta related. Although the answer below seems to have it like me.

Comment: Well, I think all is about timers - two many unmanaged and not stopped explicitly, so they can just overlap on unlucky moment of interruption. You have to keep references to timers and cancel them explicitly on stop activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach by setting a specific .id for the view and changing it on reset, forcing a redraw of the subview:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var startBreathingAnimation = false
    @State var inhaling = false
    @State var infoText = "Start a mediation"
    @State var viewID = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ZStack {
                if startBreathingAnimation {
                    BreathAnimation(inhaling: $inhaling)
                        .id(viewID) // here
                        .onChange(of: inhaling) { newValue in
                            if newValue {
                                infoText = "Breath in..."
                            } else {
                                infoText = "Breath out..."
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            Text(infoText)
            Button("Toggle") {
                if startBreathingAnimation {
                    startBreathingAnimation = false
                    infoText = "Start your meditation" 
                    inhaling = false
                } else {
                    startBreathingAnimation = true
                    viewID = UUID()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I tried it. And it worked. But now a new bug has entered the code. The animation is out of sync. If I toggle the animation repeatedly the breath in and breath out parts are longer, shorter, and weirder. Have you seen this, too? Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to ChrisR's answer, which helped give me a fresh subview, but created the problem of out-of-sync animation property values, I used the help of PreferenceKeys. PreferenceKeys are apparently not that known among many intermediate SwiftUI devs, so I thought I'd share it here briefly.

Swiftful Thinking has a great video on them: [link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnbBc00lqWU&list=PLwvDm4Vfkdphc1LLLjCaEd87BEg07M97y)

A binding to a subview and its parent creates a way to strong connection for my case. I only want to observe the inhaling property of BreathAnimation() on my MainView().

That's when PreferenceKeys come into play.

Here is the code that helped me solve my issue.

Create a property that can be accessed from all views if needed:

```swift
struct InhalingPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: Bool = false
    
    static func reduce(value: inout Bool, nextValue: () -> Bool) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

// Housekeeping that lets us update the preference key in our childview
extension View {
    
    func updateInhalingPreferenceKey(_ isInhaling: Bool) -> some View {
        preference(key: InhalingPreferenceKey.self, value: isInhaling)
    }
    
}
```

Add this to the childview and connect it to the BreathAnimation property inhaling:

```swift
var body: some View { 
    VStack {
// Content of child view

    }
    .updateInhalingPreferenceKey(inhaling)
}
```

And finally, we can access the childview property by using this:

```swift
.onPreferenceChange(InhalingPreferenceKey.self, perform: { inhaling in
    self.inhaling = inhaling
}) // self.inhaling is the parentview property
```

This together with ChrisR's solution for fresh child views helped me achieve what I wanted. Hope this might help someone else as well!